# Trouble installing Timeplot in RHEL

Tags: haskell, rhel6

When installing [Timeplot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Timeplot) in RHEL 6 using the following command

```
cabal install timeplot
```

I get the following error:

```
Data/Array/IArray.hs:1:14: Unsupported extension: Trustworthy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install timeplot I needed to install the haskell-platform and cairo-devel package (from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)) with

```
sudo yum install haskell-platform cairo-devel
```

Then install gtk2hs-buildtools

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
```

Open a new terminal at this point to get the new $PATH that includes $HOME/.cabal/bin

You many need to manually install strptime-1.0.6, as strptime-1.0.7 gave me the following error

```
building strptime-1.0.7...

Data/Time/Parse.hsc:22:18:
    Could not find module `Foreign.ForeignPtr.Unsafe':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Install strptime-1.0.6 with

```
cabal install strptime-1.0.6
```

Then install timeplot

```
cabal install timeplot
```

Comment: I'm very surprised. Just looking at the error you posted, I would expect "upgrade GHC" to be in the solution somewhere -- did `yum install haskell-platform` do this behind the scenes for you?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I have no idea. This was the first time I attempted to use cabal, so I just kept trying commands until something worked.

Answer (score 0):

Timeplot probably depends on a newer array than what comes with the installed GHC or platform, and thus it tries to pull it off hackage. And the new array (that is selected by default) is not backwards compatible with older GHCs.